# Compiler error after importing TextMesh Pro

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use TextMesh pro in my unity project. However, after importing the package from the asset store, I received 56 errors immediately. Some of them are the following:

> Assets/TextMesh Pro/Examples & Extras/Scripts/VertexZoom.cs(16,17): >error CS0433: The type 'TMP_Text' exists in both 'TextMeshPro-2017.3->Runtime, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and >'Unity.TextMeshPro, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, >PublicKeyToken=null'
>
> Assets/TextMesh Pro/Examples & >Extras/Scripts/TMP_ExampleScript_01.cs(17,17): error CS0433: The type >'TMP_Text' exists in both 'TextMeshPro-2017.3-Runtime, >Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and >'Unity.TextMeshPro, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, >PublicKeyToken=null'

After reading some posts online, it seems that unity has a built in TextMesh pro package, but how do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Which version of unity are you using. If it 2018.2 or above you don't need to download from asset store its already part of unity. you can check from window > package manager

Comment: I experienced this when I tried to update my project using 2018.3. You just need to delete the TextMesh Pro files from the old version, and I believe you have to do some re-mapping in case you are already using TMP from the old version.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have 2 text mesh pro packages, try deleting one or upgrade to latest version of unity